# 13.04 stopped playing streams in Rhythbox and totem

Tags: rhythmbox, streaming, totem, gstreamer

The stream does not play in Rhythmbox nor totem. It played fine before the upgrade; it looks like a regression from [an earlier report about the same](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146795/totem-wont-stream-media-files). The streams play in mplayer and play fine when downloaded with wget and then opened in totem. I suspect there is either a bug in gstreamer, or I am missing some component of gstreamer, somehow.

1. Is this a known bug: if so where can I help debug it?
2. What part, package or addong for gstreamer manages streaming of mp3?
3. Is rhythbox using gstreamer at all? If not, I am probably looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Same problem here, makes the Radio Lens useless.

Comment: I did not know about radio-lenses, but this strengthens my idea that this is a gstreamer-bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems to be a gvfs bug [Bug #1153934](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1153934?comments=all).

When clicking a radio stream in rhythmbox, nothing seems to happen, except the stream is being downloaded in the background. When killing the process 'gvfsd-http' while the stream secretly downloads, rhythmbox starts to play.

Comment: Any update or patch that can be installed to fix this. Thanks?