# Adding radio station to Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox

The only reason why I install Banshee on my new ubuntu distros is because i cannot seem to be able to add my favorite radio station to Rhythmbox.

I would like to add this radio station to Rhythmbox `http://live-icy.gss.dr.dk:80/A/A05H.mp3`

I press add radio and enter the radio URL in this box:

[image: http://imgur.com/WThmCrl]

Now when i try to start the radio nothing happens

Any help appreciated

**edit 1**

Ubuntu 13.10

Rhythmbox 2.99.1

Comment: Do you have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed, as mp3 is a proprietary format? (You might want to check [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1335781))

Comment: Well, if the radio station works in banshee that cannot be the problem can it?

Comment: that is true indeed... Can you specify what version of GNU/Linux Ubuntu and Rhythmbox you are using?

Comment: So it looks like a [bug in 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289258/13-04-stopped-playing-streams-in-rhythbox-and-totem) and will be [fixed in trusty](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsoup2.4/+bug/1153934?comments=all) I understand... Could you please verify?